# how to keep equal number of flex children per line when items are added

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I am looking for a solution to keep an (approximately) equal number of items per row when flexbox wraps, for a case with an **arbitrary** number of children. The closest answers I found were really about specifying a fixed number of children per row at different breakpoints - that is, if six (somehow all the examples are six) children will fit on a line at a certain breakpoint then great, if not then three per line, etc. I know how to change widths per breakpoint, and I know at least four ways to hardcode a flexbox line wrap after a specific arbitrary element - if I know which elment to break on in advance.

This case is different in that I can't know how many children the element will have, however. I know that at a certain breakpoint, I can fit up to five on a row; so if there are five children, then I want a single row, but if there are six children, then I want two rows of three elements. If there are eight, then two rows of four, if ten, then two rows of five, at twelve we get three rows of four, etc. (other numbers need to end up with one fewer on the bottom row - that's all fine.)

I have complete control over the markup, and I'm willing to use javascript if necessary (it probably is). I'm not currently using jQuery and don't particularly want to add a package just for this, but I can if needed and I'm decent at translating jQuery back into vanilla javascript anyway, so go ahead and give me a jQuery solution if that's what you've got. I'm not married to flexbox on principle either, but I'm using align-items: stretch to get the look I want when there's an different number in the last row, so I'm pretty sure grid can't do what I want. If it'll come close, I'll at least learn something. Heck, I'll even look at weird hacky things with floats and max/min width at this point.

Comment: I might be completely missing the question here, but what's stopping you from doing percentages for your child elements with a classic flex grid kind of setup / layout if you know your breakpoints? I think if you do "mobile first" (or whichever lowest breakpoint you have) and work your way up, you'll remove a lot of the confusion you're facing yourself. If you know Bootstrap, then you can take inspiration from their grid layouts. 3 pr row is col-3. Then when you reach the breakpoint where you can have 5 pr. row, you simply write custom css in a media query from that point on, using percent

Comment: Also, keep in mind that CSS has a calc() method, which comes very handy when you want to take your gutters (i.e. spacing/margin) into consideration. That's what Bootstrap does as well.

Comment: Yup, you're missing the question. This is NOT about re-wrapping elements at different breakpoints depending on what fits. (I've got that part down) This is about not knowing the number of elements in advance, and trying to lay them out evenly anyway.

Comment: Could you define what evenly means a bit more. The most even in every general case is one item per row so there must be some other constraint.

Comment: then you can do nth-child(n+5), and if you can't make it happen with that, then you have to resort to a JS solution.